# Is it bad to introduce snippet formatting?

Tags: discussion, edits, rejected-edits, stack-snippets

I recently submitted an edit to a new user's html/js post changing their code block to a Stack Snippet. [My edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15509625) with the non-critical message. Should it have been accepted, or is it bad to edit in a Snippet?

Comment: to me the edit seems pointless. there's nothing in the edited code block that would execute and display in a snippet which to me is the reason why you'd put html/css/js into a snippet, to have it execute and demonstrate the problem/solution

Comment: Even if the snippet did execute meaningfully, there's a whole bunch of indentation added which looks plain ugly, and indicates not much effort was put into making the edit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The post was rejected *by the OP*, with the *Reject and Edit* button. This button carries an automatic reason. Given that the user is not that experienced with Stack Overflow yet, and has made several more edits to the post, I'd not read too much into this rejection.

That said, there is no point in putting a JS block into a snippet; there is nothing to demonstrate here, you can't run that block in your browser to illustrate the issue the OP is facing.

Answer (score 4):

I think the edit made post worse - it pretends that code can be executed with some sensible result (which is at best unlikely in this case) and thus adds extra non-functional UI elements into the post.

So I would reject the edit if I see it in review queue. It would be better as comment to OP with link to explanation of snippets.